# GPU для нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, gpu

Обучаю нейронную сеть с применением CUDA на Python. Для данной задачи рассматривается два варианта GPU:

- RTX 3090 (количество CUDA 10496, частота ядра 1400 МГц, память GDDR6X, Технологический процесс 8 нм);
- Tesla A100 (количество CUDA 7936, частота ядра 1100 МГц, память HBM2e, Технологический процесс 7 нм).

Если не вдаваться в нюансы, в первом приближении какой GPU подойдет лучше? Критерий выбора - скорость работы (количество операций в ед. времени или задержка) при прочих равных условиях. Объём памяти для меня не является приоритетным критерием.
Понимаю, что вопросы подбора железа нельзя здесь задавать, но у проблематично их где-либо сравнить. Можно, конечно попробовать облака, но хотелось бы узнать в теории.

Comment: Ну вот тут например что-то сравнивают https://bizon-tech.com/gpu-benchmarks/NVIDIA-RTX-3090-vs-NVIDIA-A100/579vs592#benchmarks и вроде Tesla в 2 раза быстрее. Только стоит она при этом в 3 раза дороже в России, если я правильно понял. Или цена вообще не важна? )

Answer (score 1):

Основные преимущества "A100" - тензорные ядра и память. При использовании TensorFlow на "A100", вы *можете* получить заметный прирост производительности в *определённых случаях*, за счёт тензорных ядер.

- A100 features 6912 CUDA Cores and 432 Tensor cores
- RTX3090 features 10496 CUDA Cores and 328 Tensor cores

Тензорные ядра работают только данными float16, что несколько уменьшает пользу от них в целом. Если вы можете правильно их использовать, то покупка "A100" оправдана. Кроме того, "A100" для PCI-ex несёт 40GB памяти с 512-битной шиной, в то время как "RTX3090" имеет лишь 24GB памяти с 384-битной шиной. В итоге, выбор должен основываться на том, как много данных вам надо загрузить в быструю память и насколько хорошо ваш софт утилизирует тензорные ядра.